# Twitter API - Is there anyway to retrieve the scraped text & image from a tweet?

Tags: twitter

When someone posts a tweet that only contains a URL, Twitter does a bit of scraping where it grabs some text and an image from the webpage.

Example below:

[image]

Is there any way of retrieving this data from the Twitter API? I've not been able to find this data in anything that's returned. Do I need to provide some special parameter maybe? Or is this just something that's not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot get that data from the Twitter API.

The data that you're seeing is a [Twitter Card](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started).

Here's how it works.

The web developer puts some meta tags in their web page - take a look at the source for https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/04/well/move/for-your-brains-sake-keep-moving.html and you'll see:

```
<meta name="twitter:site" value="@nytimes" />
<meta property="twitter:url" content="https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/04/well/move/for-your-brains-sake-keep-moving.html" />
<meta property="twitter:title" content="For Your Brain’s Sake, Keep Moving" />
<meta property="twitter:description" content="Exercise changes the workings of new brain cells in ways that may protect against dementia, a study in mice suggests." />
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/10/10/well/04physed-brain-photo/04physed-brain-photo-videoSixteenByNineJumbo1600.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" value="summary_large_image" />
```

When Twitter sees a URL, it fetches it and looks for those tags. If it finds them, it will display a photo and headline on the Twitter website.

If you want to retrieve that data, you need to visit the URL and look for the [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/) tags.

Comment: Is there no API call to force a scrape, like there is with Facebook's? My images have daily changing data in them so I can't rely on twitter automatically re-caching when it chooses.